# Styling React Modal with data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, custom-data-attribute

I'm adding color themes (light/dark mode) to my application however, the styling does not affect my modal, built using react-modal. I am using data attributes and CSS variables to switch between themes, with the attribute within a div with class name App. The issue is that the React Portal that contains the Modal is a sibling element to the root div, which is the parent div to App. Thus, the Modal only inherits the CSS variables from :root and not from the [data-theme='dark'] data attribute. What would be the best workaround to this issue? I've thought of the following possible solutions:

- Expanding the scope of the data attributes so that it lies in body, therefore encompassing the React Portal.
- Setting the colors for the React Modal through JavaScript and getting the proper colors from other elements.
- Reworking the way I am implementing different themes (least favorable solution as it works for all other parts of my application)

Screenshots of DOM:
[[image]Modal closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jodty.png)

[[image]Modal open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/monSk.png)

CSS:

```
:root {
  --color-background: #F8F0E3;
  --color-background-secondary: #E3EBF8;
  --color-background-third: #E3EBF8;
  --color-text: #000000;
  --color-text-alternate: #757575;
  --theme-color-strong: #FFFFFF;
  --color-background-highlight: #6F7378;
  --color-background-opaque: rgba(248, 240, 227, 0.75);
  --color-link: #0000EE;
  --color-button: #FFFFFF;
  --okay-color: #F9E076;
}
[data-theme='dark'] {
  --color-background: #121212;
  --color-background-secondary: #181818;
  --color-background-third: #caced3;
  --color-text: #FFFFFF;
  --color-text-alternate: #FFFFFF;
  --theme-color-strong: #000000;
  --color-background-highlight: #e6e6e6;
  --color-link: #A5C9FF;
  --color-button: #121212;
  --okay-color: #d3c404;
}
.rating-modal{
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the CSS sibling selector, you can target and apply CSS to your modal portals.
Like

```
[data-theme='dark'] + .ReactModalPortal {
   //your CSS to apply over ReactModalPortal div
}
```

And you can now target children of the ReactModalPortal div as follows

```
[data-theme='dark'] + .ReactModalPortal .rating-modal {
   //your CSS to apply over class rating-modal div
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to be working for me. My guess is that since the data attribute lies in a div underneath the root div, the attribute is not actually siblings with the .ReactModalPortal so the sibling selectors have no effect. Root and the Portal are siblings, not the div with the data attribute.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help you or not but you can do a bit hacky solution. use raw javascript to add the attribute to body using useEffect hook like
`useEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
  }, [])`

And then target both ReactModalPortal and other root components