# Can you set body id dynamically in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement dark mode in my app.
The idea is to add this to the root element:

```
  <div id="dark">
```

And then this in CSS:

```
#dark {
  background-color: #1A1A2E;
}
```

And then in Css, customize each dom element by using classes. For example, here I will work on cards:

```
#dark .card-body {
  background-color: #16213E !important;;
}

#dark .card-header {
  background-color: #0F3460 !important;
}
```

Now, this works perfectly fine.
But, with [Modals](https://6-4-0--reactstrap.netlify.app/components/modals/), it does not work. I think it's because Modals are not rendered initially so for some reason the dark style does not apply to them.

What worked though is adding id="dark" to each modal:

```
#dark .modal-header {
  background-color: #0F3460 !important;
}

#dark .modal-body {
  background-color: #16213E !important;;
}

#dark .modal-footer {
  background-color: #16213E !important;;
}

  <Modal
    // dark doesn't get applied automatically for modals because apparently modals are not rendered in the beginning
    id="dark"
    isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
    toggle={this.toggleModal}
  >
    <div className="modal-header">
```

But, it'll be a pain to apply this to every single modal.

---

One solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72676360/8965420):

> Modal should be the descendant of a tag which has id="dark". It is
> loaded by the script right below the script tag and you are trying to
> put 'dark' id on some div tag and the modal doesn't lie inside it,
> thus the CSS selector not targeting it.
>
> So, you need to put id="dark" on the body tag.

---

This solves the modals issue.
But, the problem is in my original implementation of dark mode, I am controlling that id in the root component like this:

```
  // Root component
  <div id={this.state.should_enable_dark_mode ? "dark" : "default"}>
```

And `should_enable_dark_mode` is managed like this:

```
  manageDarkMode() {
    window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
      console.log("change to local storage!");
      let should_enable_dark_mode = localStorage.darkMode == "true";
      this.setState({
        should_enable_dark_mode,
      });
    });
  }
```

So the problem with the solution mentioned above is that I couldn't find a way to control the body tag from the react app. And I am not sure if it's a good thing to do.
What do you think I should do?

Comment: Please beware for your current solution that IDs need to be unique per page. You should use a class instead.

Comment: Yes, there will be only one html elemnt with id="dark". The modal solution I tried initially was just to test things out.

Comment: There is a closely related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640883/styling-react-modal-with-data-attribute unfortunately not yet with an answer either

Comment: Your modals are most likely inside a portal, which is outside of your app root. It might help to know which library you are using to implement Bootstrap in React. Is it [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)?

Comment: It's Reactstrap

Comment: I guess your question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474803/trying-to-use-react-dom-to-set-body-styles

Comment: You might also be interested in the [`prefers-color-scheme` Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

Comment: I ended up doing this:  document.body.id = "dark"; Not sure if's the correct choice but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the comments to your original question that you decided to just modify the body element in the browser DOM, which will probably work fine since the body element is not controlled by React and will likely  not be changed by any other code.

I would however like to suggest a few improvements that makes it at bit less dirty:

- use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) like `data-display-mode="dark"` as a target for your CSS selectors instead of the ID. IDs are supposed to be stable and other tools and libraries (e.g. UI test tools) might rely on this.
- use the `Modal.container` property to attach your Modals to the `App` element (the React-controlled global parent div defined in your React code, which you can control, not the app-root-div in index.html). Then set your `data-display-mode` attribute here by React-means. This way you will not bypass the virtual DOM.
- use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for defining your colors, and then define all dark mode modifications in one place. Don't spread your dark-mode-styling code across multiple class selectors - you will have a hard time maintaining this.